# Why is the set of all binary sequences not countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is wrong with this reasoning:
The union (finite or infinite) of countable sets is countable.
The set of all binary sequences is the infinite union of the sets $S_n$ of all the binary sequences of length $n$, which are finite, hence countable.

Comment: You haven't accounted for all the infinite binary sequences, only the finite ones of any length.

Comment: Also, it is not true that an infinite union of countable sets is always countable. A union of _countably many_ countable sets if countable, but the union of uncountably many sets each of which is countable may not be. For example $\bigcup_{x\in [0,1)} (\mathbb Z+x)$ is $\mathbb R$ which is not countable.

Comment: @AlexJBest thanks for the response; I was fearing it will exactly this response, as I cannot make the difference between the two..

Comment: @Radu probably one cannot understand the difference between countable and uncountable without first understanding the difference between finite and infinite

Comment: @TrevorWilson indeed, I am under the (obviously wrong, as it has already been pointed out) impression that my finite sequences can grow without bound, hence cover all infinite sequences..

Comment: Every infinite sequence is _approximated_ by finite sequences, growing without bound, but it is not the same as any of these finite sequences that approximate it (because they are finite and it is not.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The set of all **finite** binary sequences **is** countable, by the argument that you gave in your question. The set of all **infinite** binary sequences is **not** countable, by [Cantor’s diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). But the two sets are completely different; indeed, they’re disjoint.

Comment: Thanks. The last word was the most important. So none of the sequences I mentioned were actually in the set in question. It remains only to try to figure out what these beasts actually are

Comment: @Radu: You’re welcome. Yes, that’s right, assuming that you really meant to count the infinite sequences.

Comment: I am sadly stuck here. I cannot, after some thought, figure out where these infinite sequences come from. Not induction, those are just finite of any length, I am told. Are they a consequence? Are they due to an axiom?  Is it simply postulated that they exist and are larger than any n I could come up with?

Comment: @Radu: I’m not sure what you mean by *where they come from*. They are simply functions from $\Bbb N$ to the set $\{0,1\}$; the existence of that set of functions follows from the usual axioms of set theory, as does the proof that there are uncountably many such functions.

Comment: @Radu: If it’s any consolation, you’re not alone in that. And I can’t help too much there, because it’s something that always seemed very natural to me.