# Has there been a concrete (dis)proof of the Continuum Hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory

I know that the continuum hypothesis has been shown to be neither true nor false.

However, I think I have come across a disproof of the hypothesis. So in relation to this, has there been any concrete disproof of the continuum hypothesis ever given before?

Here's a basic idea of what I thought could disprove the Continuum Hypothesis:

Consider the set B of all possible binary sequences. Then set B is countable (for reference see [why is the set of all binary sequences not countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338094/why-is-the-set-of-all-binary-sequences-not-countable)). Now since this set is countably infinite, we know that

$$|B| = a$$

I have used the symbol $a$ in place of the traditional symbol of aleph-zero.

Now if I try to compute the cardinality of B using permutations, I get

$$|B| = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2+... + 2^a$$ (counting all possible strings of all lengths. The last term is $2^a$ because the length of a binary sequence of infinite length is a countable infinity)

So, if I combine the above 2 equations,
$$2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2+... + 2^a = a$$
Computing the sum of the geometric progression on the left (there is no constraint in the derivation of this formula which says that it cannot be applied for infinite terms)
$$2^0 (2^a - 1)/(2-1) = 2^a - 1$$

However, if the continuum hypothesis were to be true, we have just shown that the cardinality of the set B is an uncountable infinity ($ = 2^a - 1$), which is false.
Therefore, the continuum hypothesis cannot be true.

There may be errors in this reasoning, so I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: "I know that the continuum hypothesis has been shown to be neither true nor false." You can't know this because it isn't true.

Comment: It has been shown that there are models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which satisfy $\mathsf{CH}$ and that there are models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which do not satisfy $\mathsf{CH}$.

Comment: @JamesBond Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#Independence_from_ZFC

Comment: I presume you meant to say "the continuum hypothesis has not been proven to be true nor  has it proven to be false".  That is not at all the same a "has been shown to be neither true nor false"!  Any proposition must be one or the other.

Comment: You might want to read: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859089/cant-prove-continuum-hypothesis/ and also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494099/why-is-ch-true-if-it-cannot-be-proved/ as well as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189471/why-is-the-continuum-hypothesis-not-true, but generally there are many disproofs of the continuum hypothesis starting from certain theories (e.g. $\sf ZFC+PFA$ can disprove the continuum hypothesis). If you didn't have any "additional hypotheses", then you are almost likely to be wrong, though.

Comment: In fact, I almost feel like this question should be closed as a duplicate of one of the links I provided. If anyone agrees, feel free to initiate this, and ping me.

Comment: As others said, if ZF is consistent, then there can be no proof of the continuum hypothesis in ZFC. So your proof (assuming it is in ZFC) is either wrong (which most would deem very very likely), or it is a proof that there is a genuine contradiction in ZF. Eitherway, it is best to try to understand what can be false in your proof, or what assumptions aren't theorems in ZFC, so you could post it here, or think for yourself.

Comment: I think the only way something useful can come out of this question is if you describe your claimed proof that CH fails.

Comment: @aduh I made the conclusion "neither true nor false" after reading this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189471/why-is-the-continuum-hypothesis-not-true

Comment: So many errors, I have to go and take a nap.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am sorry if that is the case. Could you please let me know my errors because this has been puzzling me for a very long time

Comment: There are several errors.  The set $B$ is only countable if it consists of _finite_ binary sequences, so there should be no last term $2^a$.  Contrary to what you say, the formula for geometric series does _not_ make sense for infinite sums (for one thing, subtraction of infinite cardinals is not well-defined).  Finally, I have no idea what you are trying to say when you say "if the continuum hypothesis were to be true": the continuum hypothesis has nothing to do with the argument you are making.

Comment: I meant to use a proof by contradiction in the last line. If the hypothesis were true, we get $|B| = $uncontable infinity, which is false. Hence, our assumption must be false. You are right about the last term, I agree with that. That _is_ wrong. But I didn't understand your point about the subtraction of infinite cardinals. Aren't _all_ cardinals treated as "regular" numbers, which is why they are used as indices of 2 in the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @EricWofsey Also thank you for your feedback. Learnt a lot of new things

Comment: Btw am I right to say that $|B| = a$? It is a countable infinity right? Is there anything wrong in saying this?

Comment: $$\Huge\textbf{Cardinals are not real numbers!}$$

Comment: As @Eric wrote, you only have $B$ countable if you include *just* the finite strings (as Brian answered in the linked question that you provide as motivation). Moreover, you should know by Cantor's theorem, that $a<2^a$. So it is impossible to have $2^a+\text{other stuff}=a$. Finally, Cardinals are not real numbers, and you cannot apply the same principles to both, especially when dealing with infinitary summations. And since there is no such thing as "regular numbers", I suggest that it might be a good idea to spend a year or two learning about ordinals and cardinals.

Answer (score 3):

The continuum hypothesis has been shown to be [independent of ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#Independence_from_ZFC), which means that, assuming ZFC is consistent, it cannot be proved or disproved in ZFC (and that both ZFC + CH and ZFC + ¬CH are consistent). Consequently, any proof or disproof (in ZFC) is incorrect.

Comment: Well, any proof that uses only the ZFC axioms...

Comment: @aduh alright :)

Comment: Fair, I'll reword.